# No ajax response in laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm taking an input from user named as `category`. On every key up i want to perform an ajax request to search if category with the similar name exists or not. If yes, then a there is a blank div below that input which i want to fill with the similar name categories.

So i created a form. Used ajax via jquery but i'm not receiving the response.

This is the jquery ajax code that i'm using

```
$("#category").keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "categories/categoryajaxrequest",
        type: "get",
        data: {
            category: $("#category").val()
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#category_suggestion").html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

This is the route part which is used as url in ajax request

```
Route::get('categories/categoryajaxrequest', array('as' =>'categoryajaxrequest', 'uses' =>'CategoryController@categoryAjaxRequest'));
```

and this is the controller part

```
//app/controllers/CategoryController.php

....

public function categoryAjaxRequest(){
    echo "working";
}
```

So, the input text has an id of "category" and below the input, there is a div with an id of "category_suggestion". At every keyup on the input, i expect it to perform an ajax request and show "success" in div . But it's not doing anything.

However, if i go directly to "/categories/categoryajaxrequest" on my browser, it outputs "working".

Comment: ...i just got a 408 error the first time I accessed this SO page. Spooky??

Comment: Change your url to `categoryajaxrequest`?

Comment: Changing url to `categoryajaxrequest` didn't help. Still same response

Comment: Try changing type: "get" to type: 'GET',

Comment: and change "categories/categoryajaxrequest" to "/categories/categoryajaxrequest"

Comment: it worked after changing url to `{{URL::action('CategoryController@categoryAjaxRequest')}}`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the action directly in the `url:` property of the `$.ajax()` method,  then no route is needed:

Laravel gives us the liberty to do that. The curly braces `{{`  `}}`  are used in views. As the JavaScript stuff is usually called in a view, it is legitim to do it that way.

The `URL::action` part is described in the docs as follows:

> To generate a URL to a controller action, we may use the URL::action
>   method or the action helper method:
>
> ```
> $url = URL::action('FooController@method');
>
> $url = action('FooController@method');
> ```

So the combination of the template system & the `URL::action` gives us the possibility of doing it this way:

```
$("#category").keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{URL::action('CategoryController@categoryAjaxRequest')}}",
        type: "get",
        data: {
            category: $("#category").val()
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#category_suggestion").html(response);
        }
    });
});
```